# How to add an object property to another property in the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm setting up actions and reducers in my react-redux app. I need a function to update a property in the state and add objects to its list, if possible with the spread syntax. Here's what I have so far:

```
const defaultState = {
  genres: {}
}

export default function(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_GENRE':
      return {
        ...state,
        genres[action.name]: action.list //new code here
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I need the genres property to be dynamically accessible like an array using its property name like so:

```
const getMusicFromGenre = (genre) => {
  return state.genres[genre];
}
```

The reducer should accept the following action, then modify the state accordingly:

```
// action
{
  type: 'ADD_GENRE,
  name: 'Rock',
  list: ['Bohemian Rhapsody', 'Stairway to Heaven', 'Hotel California']
}

// old state
{
  genres: {
    "Pop": ['Billie Jean', 'Uptown Funk, 'Hey Jude']
  }
}

// new state
{
  genres: {
    "Pop": ['Billie Jean', 'Uptown Funk, 'Hey Jude'],
    "Rock": ['Bohemian Rhapsody', 'Stairway to Heaven', 'Hotel California']
  }
}
```

I'm willing to use a different approach if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but need to handle each level of nesting separately.  Here's an example I wrote for http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html :

```
function updateVeryNestedField(state, action) {
    return {
        ....state,
        first : {
            ...state.first,
            second : {
                ...state.first.second,
                [action.someId] : {
                    ...state.first.second[action.someId],
                    fourth : action.someValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to read some of the articles on immutable data handling that I have linked at http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html#immutable-data-management and https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md .

Comment: I was trying to find the solution myself, but the problem was too difficult to google. Thanks for the links, definitely going to read that over a big cup of coffee tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

[immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) is a very useful library for doing state updates.  In your situation it would be used like this, which will create a new array if there are no existing items, or concat the existing items with the action's list if there are pre-existing items:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const defaultState = {
  genres: {}
}

const createOrUpdateList = (prev, list) => {
   if (!Array.isArray(prev)) {
       return list;
   }
   return prev.concat(list);
   // or return [...prev, ...list] if you prefer
}

export default function(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_GENRE':
      return update(state, {
          genres: {
              [action.name]: {
                  $apply: prev => createOrUpdate(prev, action.list)
              }
          }
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a helpful plugin, makes the code easier to look at. Thank you